Next.js 14 & OneTrust: OneTrust blocks my route chunks by marking it with type="text/plain"
I have a Next.js 14 website with OneTrust integrated into it. It looks like OneTrust blocks my route chunks if certain consent were not provided.
I believe, to solve this, I need to add data-to-ignore to my webpack-generated chunks.
I already tried the solution here: Next JS add data attributes to script tags but can't seem to make it work as I am using Next.js 14 (with App Router)
Or maybe there's a way thru Next config or Webpack config to automatically add data-ot-ignore attribute to all my script chunks?
What I wanna achieve is that all my webpack-generated chunks be tagged with data-ot-ignore by default so that OneTrust does not modify its type into type="text/plain"

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
